# What would Pangaea's Climate look like?

Tags: climate, geography

I'm building a world as close to the real Pangaea as possible. And I was wondering what the climate would look like. I've read other answers to similar questions but they haven't described the entire map. Also, in my understanding, the changes in wind circulation would greatly affect where deserts and forests are found, and if so, can someone describe roughly how the continent would look like?

This is the map I'm currently using because of its simplicity.
[image: Text]

I understand that most of the insides would be deserts, but how would the vast rivers you see in the image affect it? How about the enormous lakes and seas? Would they provide sufficient moisture for forests and vegetation to grow?

Comment: none of the river in the image will be part of pangea, those are modern rivers. Also here is a better map of pangea. https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ec/Pangaea_200Ma.jpg

Comment: @John -- There are actually quite a few rivers that date back to those times! The Rhine, Susquehanna, Meuse & a few others all predate the breakup of Pangea. The Finke, and possibly the Meuse, even predate Pangea itself.

Comment: @elemtilas source please, I have never heard a date for the Rhine even close to 200 millions years. Note the Susquehanna and Meuse don't show up on that map. The Finke followed a vastly different course back then, not does it show up on this map.

Comment: @John -- [List of Rivers by Age](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_rivers_by_age) and age of [Pangea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pangaea) itself along with approximate times of formation & breakup. Disclaimer: I'm not a geologist! But it seems that if Pangea began to break up about 175 Mya and there're rivers that date to 200 to 400 Mya, it stands to reason that those rivers would be in play for the OP! Also, complaining that the cartographer's choice of what rivers to put on a map affects what I said is a straw man attack. Just draw the river in! And also, yes rivers do change course!

Comment: @elemtilas fine change my statment to the majority of the rivers on the map, the point still stands, most of the rivers on the map did not exist at the time. water ways on that map tell you basically nothing about waterways at the time.  one easy way to tell, they drain to coastlines that were nor coastlines at the time, and/or drain away from mountain ranges that did not exist at the time. heck north America probably probably drained from the Appalachians to the west coast.

Comment: @John -- No need to get snarky! You have a valid point: not all rivers are old. But on the other hand the map is part of the description of the OP's world. The OP says "this is the map I'm currently using because of its simplicity". Since this isn't actually a map of Pangea and since the OP isn't talking about a time hundreds of millions of years ago, I'm not sure why you'd even bring up the fact that the rivers don't exist. They're on the OP's map! I think the best way to look at this kind of question is from a kind of "fictional present" rather than "real Earth past history".

Comment: I appreciate both of your input, I never really realised my map was that off. I thought it looked the best and looked pre similar to the one in the wiki, so I chose that one. The real Pangaea seems to be a better setting but do you guys know any good maps that are as simple and has modern borders just like the one I provided? @elemtilas I'm glad somebody could get my point and saw the problems I had, thanks. I'm also very new to this website, is there a way to DM people here? If not, could I possibly get your discord or smth?

Comment: (:  Actually I think the map you're using is perfectly fine. It's the best one I've seen with modern national borders. [This one has continental borders only.](https://inhisimagedotblog.files.wordpress.com/2018/03/pangea.png). It's not like anyone really knows what the actual coastline of Pangea looks like, so I'd say this one is good enough, until you draw your own map!  As for DM, that's a negatory at Stack Exchange. You're certainly welcome to join the [CBB](https://cbbforum.com), an excellent long format discussion forum for worldbuilders and language inventors. You can find me there!

Comment: Thank you so much! I've fallen in love with sites like these where fellow worldbuilders can discuss fantasy things with people that have extensive knowledge of physics.

Answer (score 2):

Most ideas for a Pangea like supercontinents depict them kind of like Australia on steroids, most of life is on the coast, the rest of the interior is just desert.  Now the reason for that is because rain has a lot farther to travel the bigger the landmass is, and if there are mountains in the way creating a rainshadow, it only gets worse.  So think of the continent in layers, deserts in the center, grasslands or mountains around them, and any and all forests or jungles only existing on the coast.

Comment: I understand, but a ton of other posts also suggest that it isn't that bad. Some posts say that leaving it as that is an over-exaggeration. When I asked the question, I was expecting someone to tell me a little bit more in detail (Which is a very bold favour of me to ask.) because I'm very curious to see how stuff like the vast rivers created by the spaces between continents and countries and the vast lakes and archipelagos affects their surroundings.

Comment: In summary, I understand that most of the insides are deserts and all, but would the rivers you see in the picture break those said deserts in pieces?

Comment: Not going to happen. This is because we only have limited geological and fossil records available to us to paint a picture of the entire continent. And as noted above what we do have paints a picture of a dry interior with only short seasonal wet periods at best. So many of those rivers, if they existed at all would only flow seasonally (like in Australia).

Comment: Part 2: So while there would have been lots of small coastal rivers, as far as numerous large inland rivers draining extensive water basins go? No, not that we can tell based on the fossil record and climate modelling etc. Which is not to say there weren't any large interior rivers at all - just not as many as seem to shown on your map.

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed answer! Appreciate it. I would've thought that with the continents merging with each other, there would be tons of rivers forming from the spaces where land couldn't fully merge.